# How do I resize child element of a grid after changing rowspan?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a standard WPF Grid with some Border elements in some of the cells (which in turn contain some content.

I need to resize some of these at runtime, so I am procedurally setting the RowSpan of said elements, like this:

```
int span = Grid.GetRowSpan(cell);
Grid.SetRowSpan(cell, ++span);
```

I've verified that the span is actually getting set, but the problem is that the Border element stays the same size and moves to the vertical center of the span. E.g. when the span is 2, it floats in between the two rows.  How do I trigger a resize of the element?  I've tried to call InvalidateArrange(), InvalidateMeasure(), and also InvalidateVisual(), but none of these affected any change.

Comment: I dont see a [`SetRowSpan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.grid.setrowspan.aspx) function that takes only an `int` parameter, can you post the full code, including any adding of rows to the `Grid` and the xaml.

Comment: @SwDevMan81 Sorry, I edited.  I am passing the element as the first parameter, I mistyped that in the post.  The full code for generating the grid is lengthy, is there a particularly relevant part that you think might be incorrect?  I'm adding the elements with the standard Grid.SetRow(), Grid.SetColumn(), etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set property `VerticalAlignment` on your `Border` element to `VerticalAlignment.Stretch`, so that it stretches inside available space in your `Grid`.

Comment: I was hoping it would be this simple, but sadly this did not work.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: `Stretch` is default `Control` alignment (if you don't specify any). @amnesia, can you provide more code (xaml where you define that grid) and screenshot (to illustrate the problem)?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figured out my mistake - cargo cult programming.  I am using an Adorner to allow the user to resize the cell content, and was vaguely following MSDN's example, and my Adorner contained the following during initialization:

```
        if (_cell.Width.Equals(Double.NaN))
            _cell.Width = _cell.RenderSize.Width;
        if (_cell.Height.Equals(Double.NaN))
            _cell.Height = _cell.RenderSize.Height;
```

This sets the width and height to allow for explicit resizing.  I misunderstood that this would actually prevent the parent from sizing the element.